# Spring Binding issue

Tags: spring-mvc

I have some objects like the two below

```
public class SavedSearch {
String title;
ArrayList<SearchParameters> params;
}

public class SearchParameter {
String field;
int operator;
String match;
}
```

On the JSP page in the input form, I use

```
<input type="text" name="title">
```

and when I breakpoint inside the FormController, the SavedSearch object has title filled in.

But the ArrayList is always empty.  It's not Spring's fault that it can't read my mind, but how do I indicate that field, operator and match are part of params?  I tried naming them paramsField, paramsOperator, paramsMatch but no luck.

I know this is not a hard question, but I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: As you've given them to us, the two classes are entirely unrelated -- is there supposed to be a relationship between them?

Answer (score 2):

for binding a List you must use special wrapper instead of ArrayList: AutoPopulatingList from Spring or LazyList from Apache Commons Collections.

some examples:

[using LazyList](http://mattfleming.com/node/134)

[using AutoPopulatingList](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=158171&postcount=3)

Comment: Thanks. Using LazyList looks very helpful and I will Google AutoPopulatingList and read up on using bind.  I had not looked at bind because I'm using 2.5 and I thought that was a pre 2.5 thing, but I will go read up.

Comment: You may use spring:bind and, for example, form:input in one JSP file, simultaneously. They are very useful for data validation.